# Where is the data stored in mysql stored?

Tags: webserver

In standard cpanel server where is it located? I mean this should probably be in server fault stackexchange but they are for experts and I am an amateur.

Is it stored separately in each account? Is it stored in the system drive?

Where?

Comment: Who you calling an amateur?

Comment: Fixed :) he he he he

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL data can be found within `/var/lib/mysql/`.

In there you may find directories for different accounts but it kinda depends on your setup.

This should give you a starting point though.